# "Open folder in Terminal" for Spotlight or Alfred

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, finder, spotlight

Is there any way in Spotlight to have a folder open in a Terminal window, either by providing an "Open in Terminal" option in search results, or (ideally) by holding down a key when selecting a result? Basically the same way holding down command will "Open containing folder" maybe make it so holding option (or whatever key) could "Open in Terminal".

Alternately, is there a way to setup the [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) app so that it will always open folder search results in the Terminal? that might be even better, then I could use ctrl-space exclusively for opening folders in the Terminal and command-space (Spotlight) for everything else.

The closest thing I can find to anything like these is the "cdto" application, which adds an "Open in Terminal" button to the Finder. This is nice, but being able to do this directly from Spotlight or with a keypress would be much more convenient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question is old and you undoubtedly found the answer by now; for the sake of completeness: the latest version of Alfred allows one to search/navigate the filesystem from within Alfred, and take action on the folder or file found. One folder action is "Open Terminal Here", which seems to be what you are asking for.

Comment: where does one fine Alfred? When I'm navigating via Finder, a right click (or CTRL click) does not offer a "Open In Terminal" or "Alfred". The best I can tell, extensions like available in Explorer or Nautilus are not allowed in OS X.

Comment: Alfred is not a standard OSX application. You need to download it [here](http://www.alfredapp.com). The OP also linked to Alfred in the original question. I highly recommend Alfred or Quicksilver if you are a spotlight user. I prefer Alfred personally because it is simpler and more up to date, but both provide the functionality requested here.

Answer (score 7):

I've found this to be the fastest method without any external tinkering.

Requirement: need to have iTerm or Terminal in the Dock:

1. Type the folder name into Alfred / Spotlight
2. Click and drag the folder that was found into the iTerm / Terminal icon in the Dock

Comment: So smart and simple! Works across all types of apps too (I was looking for a way to open a folder in my markdown editor).

Answer (score 1):

Try this tool:
https://github.com/nmadhok/OpenInTerminal

This is a really handy tool for programmers on Mac as it lets you open the folder directly in Terminal. You can select multiple folders to open them in multiple terminal windows. You can also select files to open the parent directory in Terminal. This application works with Finder as well as without Finder which is a plus!

Answer (score 1):

use this Alfred extension

https://github.com/LeEnno/alfred-terminalfinder

then just lob off the input and set it to a hotkey.. I have one to open the current finder in terminal and vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

@Verboze - I'm still looking for an answer :)

Perhaps it should be migrated to stack exchange or the other one used non-programming topics, such as system administrivia. Though a case could be made that the command line is essential to programming.....

Windows has "Command Prompt Here". Linux has Nautilus' "Open In Terminal". [The world's most advanced operating system](http://www.google.com/#q=the+world+most+advanced+operating+system) has nothing (the best I can tell).

For completeness, I did look at the customizable toolbar ('drag your favorites here'; but my favorite is missing). I also found an old Action Script or Automator Script that did not work (the article was old, and it could not be followed).

I did find a program called "CD To...", but its broken. Upon opening the first terminal, the program opens two terminals. I'm not sure what other programming mistakes were made by the developer, and I really don't want to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://github.com/miromannino/alfred-new-terminal-window

It opens a new Terminal/iTerm window in the current space. 
Holding the alt key, the new window is also opened opened in the current frontmost Finder folder.

For me that is almost sufficient for my daily work!

Hope it helps!